# Selecting a list in a list of lists in python similar to Mathematicas 'All'

Tags: python

I have a list of the format:

```
cool_list = [[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7]], [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7]]]
```

in the real world the numbers are different and have some meaning.

How would I go about selecting the `[4, 5, 6, 7]` list from all the data in `cool_list`?
I think the mathematica equivalent is something like `cool_list[[All],4]`

**EDIT:**
Output should be

```
[[4, 5, 6, 7],
[4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: By what criteria are you looking for `[4, 5, 6, 7]` (what does it satisfy that the others don't)?

Comment: what you want finally???

Comment: It is always on the same index in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the lists that are [4, 5, 6, 7] into a list:

```
[x[3] for x in cool_list]
```

Then the output is:

```
[[4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you look for

```
third_items = [x[3] for x in cool_list]
last_items = [x[-1] for x in cool_list]
```